# How to know when one app is close in the springboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want to capture when one app is closed from springboard to make one logout. But the applicationWillTerminate method doesn't work.

Does anyone kwon anything about it?

Thanks

Comment: 'closed from springboard'? means, do you want to capture closing the app from background running apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, you should go through following methods once.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
     Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
     */
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
     If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
     */
}
```

The code that you placed in `applicationWillTerminate`, put it in above mentioned methods..
Try to put your code in one of the method & check your logic works or not.

**Edit** :

you question specifies that, you want to detect the application force quit event - which is not possible. ( sorry but not in my hands )

The way we delete application from minimized states by double tapping - It actually means, we are force-quiting those application & That will not trigger any of our application methods as our application process is going to be killed.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to get the instant when you close the app.

Comment: @damacri86 - then you should use `applicationWillResignActive` - this will get triggered immediately.

Comment: Thanks again @Spark but it doesn't called when the app is closed from springboard :(

Comment: @damacri86 - The way we delete application from minimized states by double tapping - It actually means, we are force-quiting those application & That will not trigger any of our application methods as our application process is going to be killed.

Answer (score 1):

When you say closed you mean: when an app is closed from the recently used bar (double press on the home button).

You can't detect when an user closes your app like that since the OS just kills you app. This not closed and on close methods are being called.

Comment: Thanks, are you sure that in this case the method is not called?

Answer (score 0):

When you press home button, application doesnt quit/exit. It just goes into background. So applicationWillTerminate is not being called.

Press home button twice to verify if application is close.

Also reckon Spark's answer

Comment: Yes I know, but I want to get when you close the app with the home button pressed twice